# Facebook : graph api object delete options?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, http-delete

Facebook graph api allows you to do things using either the object id (which it generates) or object_url (which you generate). Can I delete facebook graph api object using object url?

For instance:

```
POST  https://graph.facebook.com/id={object_id or object_url}&scrape=true
```

(tells facebook to re-scrape the object from your site)

What I want to know is, can I tell facebook to delete the object using the object url?
Or do I have to keep track of the id's and use:

```
DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/{id}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only delete your own Post on the Users wall, that means you not able to delete post from other Apps. 
And you need a access token

> Deleting http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/
>
> You can delete objects in the graph by issuing HTTP DELETE requests to
>   the object URLs, i.e,
>
> DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/ID?access_token=... HTTP/1.1
>
> To support clients that do not support all HTTP methods (like
>   JavaScript clients), you can alternatively issue a POST request to an
>   object URL with the additional argument `method=delete` to override the
>   HTTP method. For example, you can delete a comment by issuing a POST
>   request to https://graph.facebook.com/COMMENT_ID?method=delete.
>
> You can delete a like by issuing a DELETE request to `/OBJECT_ID/likes`
>   (since likes don't have an ID).

Comment: Can't a group admin delete any post from the Group?